# containsMatchingElement not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

Im just trying to test an email component using `containsMatchingElement()` from the enzyme library, here is the component I'm testing:

```
import React from "react";
type Props = {
  submitted: boolean;
  email: string;
  handleChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
};
const EmailField = ({ submitted, email, handleChange }: Props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        style={{ padding: "0.75em 1em" }}
        type="text"
        className="intro-x login__input input input--lg border border-gray-300 block"
        placeholder="Email"
        name="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {submitted && !email ? (
        <h2 className="mt-1 text-theme-6">Email is required</h2>
      ) : null}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default EmailField;
```

Here is the test file, I expected toEqual to return true but false was returned:

```
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import EmailField from "./EmailField";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("rendering error message appropriately", () => {
  it("no error message", () => {
    let email = "z3376349@gmail.com";
    let handleChange = () => {};
    let submitted = true;
    const submittedAndEmailPresent = shallow(
      <EmailField submitted={submitted} email={email} handleChange={handleChange} />
    );

    expect(
      submittedAndEmailPresent.containsMatchingElement(
        <input
          style={{ padding: "0.75em 1em" }}
          type="text"
          className="intro-x login__input input input--lg border border-gray-300 block"
          placeholder="Email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      )
    ).toEqual(true);

    
  });
});
```

I am new to the enzyme library so I am guessing I am missing something quite basic. I tried removing the tailwind classes from the component but that didn't work. Am I using the `containsMatchingElement()` method correctly?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that the `handleChange function = () => {}` is considered different across the two React elements despite coming from the exact same variable; reassigning `handleChange = null` fixed everything. I wonder why this is happening.